Galois cohomology and Levi subgroups
Let $F$ a field and $G$ a smooth connected reductive group with a Levi subgroup $M$. Under what assumptions is $H^1(F, M) \to H^1(F, G)$ injective? In the case $F$ is nonarchimedean local I believe this follows from Kottwitz's description $H^1(F, G) = \pi_1(G)_{\Gamma, tors}$. Is this also true over global fields, or perhaps just a formal result that holds for all $F$?

I believe this fails when $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$, when $G$ is $\textbf{PGL}_4$ and when $M$ is $\textbf{PGL}_2\times \textbf{PGL}_2$ (coming from the parabolic whose associated homogeneous space is the Grassmannian of $2$-dimensional subspaces of a $4$-dimensional vector space).

@JasonStarr: Is the image  in ${\bf PGL}_4$ of ${\bf GL}_2\times{\bf GL}_2\subset {\bf GL}_4$  indeed ${\bf PGL}_2\times{\bf PGL}_2$ ?

@MikhailBorovoi Thanks for the correction.  That explains the discrepancy.  The semisimple factor of the image is a $\mu_2$-extension of $\mathbf{PGL}_2\times \mathbf{PGL}_2$.  That factor cancels out one of the factors of $H^1(F,\mathbf{PGL}_2) = H^2(F,\mu_2)$.

Let $P$ be a parabolic with reductive part $M$. Then it's sufficient to know the injectivity with $M$ replaced with $P$. Giving a $P$-torsor $X$ inducing the trivial $G$-torsor is the same as giving a rational point of $G/P$, but all such points lift to rational points of $G$, so $X$ must be trivial.

@KeerthiMadapusi: Why do all rational points of $G/P$ lift  to rational points of $G$?

@MikhailBorovoi See, for example, Proposition 7.2.1 in https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BW16Page/handouts/249B_2016.pdf
The proof is nontrivial, but the key point is (assuming F infinite) unirationality, and thus Zariski density of F-points
